# Why is Windows Service not picking up code changes?

Tags: c#, windows-services

I am able to run my Windows Service directly from Visual Studio without installing it by hitting F5.

I am able to do this because in Program.cs I have the section:

```
            var service = new JSpargoService();
#if DEBUG
        var logger = Log.GetLogger<JSpargoService>();
        logger.Warn("Start service as console application... for debuging purposes! Please        use 'Release' mode to run as windows service!");
        service.Start();
        Console.WriteLine("Running...");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop program!");
        Console.Read();
        service.Stop();
#else
        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
        { 
            service
        };
        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);        
#endif
```

Great, I can debug and go.
Here is my problem.
The Windows is not picking up my code changes.
So as I modify my new code, maybe add a new variable and return a result to it, when I hover over it it's like the var does not exist.

It's like it won't recompile in debug mode.
Strange.
Please help!

Answer (score 0):

Are you expecting it to recompile your code while your service is actually running? That's not going to happen.

Comment: Of course not.  I stop it. Modify the code. And restart it.  The new code is not recognized. If you hover new code there is nothing. If you hover over old code, you can see the value.
And breakpoints on new code just disappear.
But the dll in the debug folder has a date like it was just compiled. It just doesn't make sense.

Comment: Ok - so the problem is not exactly what I thought it was.
I can put "My Service starting..." and "My Service stopping..." and see it in the console window.  So I am able to make edits.
But another class the service instantiates is the one that cannot be modified and recompiled.

Comment: I finally noticed the yellow line between the code and the line numbers.  So the issue is it won't let me save the file.  But there is no asterix in the Tab of the file with the name on it.  so it looks like it has been saved.